# Is there a way to color a column using DXL?

Tags: ibm-doors

When I manually click the column properties there is an option to set column Text Color by attribute, and there is an option to set **Background Color by attribute**. I want to do this through DXL instead of manually.

I've found the DXL function that sets the **Text** Color by attribute: `color(Column c, string AtrrName)`.

However, I'm unable to find the function that sets the **Background** Color in the DXL Reference Manual. Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is in the section "Columns", page 688.

```
backgroundColor(set)

Declaration
void backgroundColo[u]r(Column c, string enumAttrName)

Operation
Sets the attribute enumAttrName as the background color for column c.

Example
Column c = column(1)
backgroundColor(c, “enumAttrName”)
Sets the background color for column c to use attribute enumAttrName.
Column c = column(1)
backgroundColor(c, “”)
Removes any previously configured background color attribute for column c.
```

It's new for DOORS 9.6.1

Comment: Thank you so, so much!! Turns out I was looking at an older version of the manual.